# How to set multidimentional session array in Yii

Tags: arrays, session, multidimensional-array, yii

I am  trying to set a `multidimensional session array` using Yii but I keep getting the following error:
**Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect**
Can someone point me in the right direction, below is the code:

```
/ $params = Util::Get_POST_Params();
    $session = Yii::app()->session;

    $session['Cart']['OfferName'] = $params['offer_name']; 
    $session['Cart']['OfferFee'] = $params['offer_fee'];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After a little reading adding creating a temp array  and using the Yii method "add" to add in the session, it did the trick form. below is the working code.

```
$session = Yii::app()->session;
    $cartArray = array('OfferName'=>$params['offer_name'],'OfferFee'=>$params['offer_fee']); 
    $session->add('cart',$cartArray);
```